# Zend Front controller

Tags: zend-framework, zend-framework-mvc, front-controller

My website(a single server) is using front controller pattern as the single entery point and I understand that only a single instance of this controller exist at any given point of time (Singleton pattern)
$frontController = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();

What surprises me is if I get concurrent requests/traffic(assume some big number) at peak times, will this single instance of the controller scale up and handle all the requests without effecting the resonse times to the customer. Why can't a pool of controller instances be made so that it scales up to the traffic?

Thank you

Comment: Apache will create the pool for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I understand it, PHP creates a brand new environment for every request, so each request will get its own individual singleton front controller sandboxed inside its own environment.